# Handling 2, 3, 4, 5 Fingers Tapped, DoubleTap & Holding Gestures in WinRT App

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-runtime

I can easily handle 1 finger `Tapped`, `DoubleTap` and `Holding` gestures like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Tapped += mc_Tapped;
    this.DoubleTapped += mc_DoubleTapped;
    this.Holding += mc_Holding;
}
public void mc_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Tap
}
public void mc_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //DoubleTap
}
public void mc_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Hold
}
```

But the events don't have a property to get the number of fingers and they don't even get fired when more than 1 touch contact is present on the screen. I also want to handle 2, 3, 4, 5 fingers `Tapped`, `DoubleTap` and `Holding` gestures. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to work with the PointerRoutedEventArgs that are passed on Pointer events (ie. Pressed, entered, released and such) and do it the hard way

Each time pointer enters the control is assigned a unique pointer ID.I would create a Dictionary and add each pointer to that dictionary as it is pressed on the control (and obviously remove them when they exit). Then in your existing tapped, double tapped and such handlers just check how many pointers are in your dictionary and call the appropriate handlers

Comment: You'll have to code around it. You can perhaps expand on the dictionary to store whether a pointer has fired the holding event and then you can check that var to see how many pointers are in holding

Comment: Program your own 'tapped'? log the time the pointer is released and then use that time to determine what happened? Its going to be hackey but I recon thats the best option. The other question is obviously Why do u want to use non standard interactions?