# Getting pinch-to-zoom x/y scale values independent of each other in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, scale, pinchzoom

How do I get the pinch-to-zoom x and y scaling values independent of each other for a Windows Store App? I'm currently using [ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationdeltaroutedeventargs.delta.aspx)'s [ManipulationDelta](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.manipulationdelta.aspx) structure, but as you can see it only offers a single scale.

```
// Global Transform used to change the position of the Rectangle.
private TranslateTransform dragTranslation;
private ScaleTransform scaleTransform;

// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Add handler for the ManipulationDelta event
    TestRectangle.ManipulationDelta += Drag_ManipulationDelta;
    dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();
    scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
    TestRectangle.RenderTransform = this.dragTranslation;
}

void Drag_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Move the rectangle.
    dragTranslation.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    dragTranslation.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

    // Scaling, but I want X and Y independent!
    scaleTransform.ScaleX = e.Delta.Scale;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY = e.Delta.Scale;
}
```

XAML:

```
<Rectangle Name="TestRectangle"
  Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Blue" 
  ManipulationMode="All"/>
```

Code mostly taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465387.aspx).

Comment: You may have to write your own gesture recognizer to do that. Not nearly as impossible or crazy as it sounds. The issue is that the pinch-zoom gesture recognizer is currently calculating a simple change in distance from the two pinch points, and is likely not calculating the direction. Take the base pinch-zoom gesture pattern, then project it to the X and Y axes.

Comment: As a side note, you may not even want to do this. Some older touchscreens have trouble when it comes to multitouch gestures and in some cases even do a pinch-zoom gesture in the axis perpendicular to the user's actual fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [Handling Two, Three, Four Fingers Swipe Gestures in WinRT App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876655/handling-two-three-four-fingers-swipe-gestures-in-winrt-app) to grab the coordinates of the two fingers, calculated the initial difference between them, and then scaled accordingly as the distance changed.

```
int numActiveContacts;
Dictionary<uint, int> contacts;
List<PointF> locationsOfSortedTouches;

void myCanvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
  PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(myCanvas);
  locationsOfSortedTouches.Add(new PointF((float) pt.Position.X, (float) pt.Position.Y));
  touchHandler.TouchesBegan(locationsOfSortedTouches);
  contacts[pt.PointerId] = numActiveContacts;
  ++numActiveContacts;
  e.Handled = true;
}

void myCanvas_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
  var pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(myCanvas);
  var ptrId = pt.PointerId;
  if (contacts.ContainsKey(ptrId)) {
    var ptrOrdinal = contacts[ptrId];
    Windows.Foundation.Point currentContact = pt.Position;
    locationsOfSortedTouches[ptrOrdinal] = new PointF((float) pt.Position.X, (float) pt.Position.Y);
    //distance calculation and zoom redraw here
  }
  e.Handled = true;
}
```