# Multiple touch points on Canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

The `Holding` event handler for `Canvas` gets triggered when the user holds down a finger, and I can figure out the position (`Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`) and put in the appropriate code.

**Problem** : When two or more fingers are pressed down on the `Canvas` at the same instant, either the `Holding` event doesn't get triggered at all or (at times) only one of them gets triggered.

**Objective** : When a user press-holds on the canvas with multiple fingers, I want to get all of the touch points, perhaps by iterating through each one or some such method.

How would I go about doing this ?

Comment: See if this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12878386/479512) on multipoint swipe gestures helps you.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT doesn't differentiate between a one-finger hold and a two-finger hold (they are all just `Hold` and trigger the same handler).

To get the number of fingers we need to use the lower-level `Pointer` messages instead of the higher-level `Hold` handlers and manipulations.